# We know that $x_{n+1}=\frac{1}{3}\left(2x_n+\frac{a}{x_n^2}\right)$. Prove ${x_n}$ is convergent

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Suppose $a>0, x_0>0$ and $x_{n+1}=\frac{1}{3}\left(2x_n+\frac{a}{x_n^2}\right)$. How to prove ${x_n}$ is convergent? Can someone helps me?

I tried to prove that $x_n$ is monotonically decreasing and have a lower bound: $a^\frac{1}{3}$.

Comment: Nice. Now you should add your attempt

Comment: I have solved your problem. Please, add your  try, then I will post my solution

Comment: OK. It seems I have solved this. Please wait a minute

Comment: thank you, VIVID, I have solved this problem by prove that ${x_n}$ is monotonic decline and have a lower bound $a^\frac{1}{3}$.

Comment: I will be honest it seems as if you haven't even attempted this question. you post questions which help the community and not a repeat one. Which already exists

Comment: It is good that you solved this. Anyway, I will post my solution since I had already written it. It may be helpful for future readers too :)

Comment: Yes, I only have a shallow consideration on this question, I would think about a question more carefully before I post it next time. Besides, thank VIVID for his detailed answers!

Comment: Also, you may consider accepting one of the answers below so that your question would not be categorized as an "Unsolved question".

Answer (score 3):

Easy to see that all terms of $(x_n)$ are positive.
Now by AM-GM, we have the lower bound:
$$x_{n+1} = \frac 13\left(x_n + x_n + \frac{a}{x_n^2}\right)\ge \sqrt[3] a, \quad (\forall n \in \mathbb N) \tag{1}$$
Also, from the given formula we have
$$x_{n+1}-x_n = -\frac{1}{3}x_n + \frac {a}{3x_n^2} = \frac{-x^3_n + a}{3x_n} \tag{2}$$
But from $(1)$ we have $$-x_n^3 \le -a$$
Plugging this into $(2)$, we have
$$x_{n+1}-x_n \le \frac{- a + a}{3x_n^2} = 0 \\ x_n \ge x_{n+1}$$
So, the sequence is decreasing and lower-bounded and, therefore, convergent.

---

Finally, let the limit be $x$. Then, we have
$$3x = 2x + \frac{a}{x^2} \\ x = \frac{a}{x^2} \implies x = \sqrt[3]a \\ \bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0AA00]{\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n = \sqrt[3]a}$$

Answer (score 3):

Rewrite$$x_{n+1}=x_n-x_n+\frac{1}{3}\left(2x_n+\frac{a}{x_n^2}\right)$$ that is to say
$$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{x_n^3-a}{3x_n^2}$$ and recognize the iterates of Newton method for solving $x^3-a=0$

Comment: Brilliant! Just please edit the last denominator as you forgot the index